# やつらも生き物だ、死して横たわる権利はあろう

Tags: words

The main character in this game enters a pact with a dragon which allows them to communicate with each other and the MC to take control of the dragon. The MC is depicted as bloodthirsty simply out for killing while the dragon as a being standing above everyone else, mocking humans especially for being a petty species.

Pretty early on in the game, when riding the dragon, you have to shoot down enemies out of the sky. After killing a certain amount, the dragon goes:

> もうやめておけ！やつらも生き物だ、死して横たわる権利はあろう。

I'm not really sure what he's trying to say here. The dragon himself seems to switch between a "let them live" and "everyone must die" mentality pretty often throughout the game and it's kinda hard to pinpoint what exactly he wants from you at times. I assume here he's mad at the MC for mindlessly killing enemies but I'm not really sure what exactly he's trying to get at here.

If 死して横たわる means "to lie dead" (which I guess it does), how does 権利 come into play here? They have a right to lie dead? Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I can't really connect your explanation with the sentence, but it perhaps means "right to rest in peace".

Comment: That was really just taking it literally, I know it doesn't really make sense. "Right to rest in peace" is interestingly also how that line was officially translated overseas (sorry, I forgot to mention this), but I still can't see how this line makes any sense in the given context. I'm supposed to kill bad guys shooting at me for which I get chastised what with that they "have the right to rest in peace" - how does this reaction make any sense? I can link a video if you like, maybe that can clear up a few things?

Comment: Yes, a video in JP version would be definitely helpful, at least I can see what's actually going on.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwFIu7lwqgk&list=PL3iekb9RQUnAhoJ2YjJ2u23zsYWOXXRSt&index=3

The mission begins at 25:00, the line is said at 25:20 (just ignore the guy speaking). Keep in mind that the main character riding the dragon has control of it as well, so what I guess is going on here is that the MC is being chastisted for needlessly slaughtering, but I can't make much sense of how the line fits here. Also doesn't help that earlier on the dragon itself was hellbent on incinerating everything in front of them, kinda makes it hard to interpret its way of thinking.

Comment: Hmm... when you watch the video, the streamer guy is apparently baffled by the line, and thinks it kind of out of context (so do I). Maybe it's said when you did some overkill attack, or hit a falling enemy, or maybe just a scripting error. It does seem a line spoken to the player character.

Comment: I noticed that too (which is why I went to search out a video of the scene with commentary, in hopes of somebody confirming my confusion haha). I suppose I'll just go with the explanation of being needlessly overkill and leave it at that. Thank you a lot for taking the time to answer my questions!

Answer (score 0):

It's a manga/anime expression (one can tell because it's extravagant). I think in this case, the speaker is saying even the baddies are living things, so they should be allowed to die and lie down (or lie down after they die) - rather than say converted into an undead, be displayed on a pike or something.

It's hard to tell what was exactly meant because it's supposed to sound mysterious.

Comment: I get it if the line was directed at the bad guy for reanimating corpses for example (of which there is no theme in this game, only some sort of mind control hinted at), but the dragon seems to chastise the MC specifically for killing, there's no theme of undead or anything here you could draw a connection to.